# deep copy nested iterable (or improved itertools.tee for iterable of iterables)

Tags: python, python-itertools, iterable

## Preface

I have a test where I'm working with nested iterables (by *nested iterable* I mean iterable with only iterables as elements).

As a test cascade consider

```
from itertools import tee
from typing import (Any,
                    Iterable)


def foo(nested_iterable: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> Any:
    ...


def test_foo(nested_iterable: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> None:
    original, target = tee(nested_iterable)  # this doesn't copy iterators elements

    result = foo(target)

    assert is_contract_satisfied(result, original)


def is_contract_satisfied(result: Any,
                          original: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> bool:
    ...
```

E.g. `foo` may be simple identity function

```
def foo(nested_iterable: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> Iterable[Iterable[Any]]:
    return nested_iterable
```

and contract is simply checks that flattened iterables have same elements

```
from itertools import (chain,
                       starmap,
                       zip_longest)
from operator import eq
...
flatten = chain.from_iterable


def is_contract_satisfied(result: Iterable[Iterable[Any]],
                          original: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> bool:
    return all(starmap(eq,
                       zip_longest(flatten(result), flatten(original),
                                   # we're assuming that ``object()``
                                   # will create some unique object
                                   # not presented in any of arguments
                                   fillvalue=object())))
```

But if some of `nested_iterable` elements is an iterator, it may be exhausted since `tee` is making shallow copies, not deep ones, i.e. for given `foo` and `is_contract_satisfied` next statement

```
>>> test_foo([iter(range(10))])
```

leads to predictable

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    test_foo([iter(range(10))])
  File "...", line 19, in test_foo
    assert is_contract_satisfied(result, original)
AssertionError
```

## Problem

How to deep copy an arbitrary nested iterable?

## Note

I'm aware of [`copy.deepcopy` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), but it won't work for file objects.

Comment: Is there any reason you are averse to simply materializing the nested iterator into a nested list, let's say?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes, I'm writing a library which works with arbitrary iterables (both finite & infinite, user-defined or from standard library), and writing property-based tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Naive solution

Straightforward algorithm would be

1. Perform elementwise copying of original nested iterable.
2. Make `n` copies of elementwise copy.
3. Obtain coordinates related to each independent copy.

which may be implemented like

```
from itertools import tee
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import (Any,
                    Iterable,
                    Tuple,
                    TypeVar)

Domain = TypeVar('Domain')


def copy_nested_iterable(nested_iterable: Iterable[Iterable[Domain]],
                         *,
                         count: int = 2
                         ) -> Tuple[Iterable[Iterable[Domain]], ...]:
    def shallow_copy(iterable: Iterable[Domain]) -> Tuple[Iterable[Domain], ...]:
        return tee(iterable, count)

    copies = shallow_copy(map(shallow_copy, nested_iterable))
    return tuple(map(itemgetter(index), iterables)
                 for index, iterables in enumerate(copies))
```

Pros:

- quite easy to read & explain.

Cons:

- if we wanted to extend our approach for iterables with greater nesting level (like iterable of nested iterables and so on) this approach doesn't look helpful.

We can do better.

## Improved solution

If we look at [`itertools.tee` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), it contains Python recipe, which with help of [`functools.singledispatch` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) can be rewritten like

```
from collections import (abc,
                         deque)
from functools import singledispatch
from itertools import repeat
from typing import (Iterable,
                    Tuple,
                    TypeVar)

Domain = TypeVar('Domain')


@functools.singledispatch
def copy(object_: Domain,
         *,
         count: int) -> Iterable[Domain]:
    raise TypeError('Unsupported object type: {type}.'
                    .format(type=type(object_)))

# handle general case
@copy.register(object)
# immutable strings represent a special kind of iterables
# that can be copied by simply repeating
@copy.register(bytes)
@copy.register(str)
# mappings cannot be copied as other iterables
# since they are iterable only by key
@copy.register(abc.Mapping)
def copy_object(object_: Domain,
                *,
                count: int) -> Iterable[Domain]:
    return itertools.repeat(object_, count)


@copy.register(abc.Iterable)
def copy_iterable(object_: Iterable[Domain],
                  *,
                  count: int = 2) -> Tuple[Iterable[Domain], ...]:
    iterator = iter(object_)
    # we are using `itertools.repeat` instead of `range` here
    # due to efficiency of the former
    # more info at
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059173/what-is-the-purpose-in-pythons-itertools-repeat/9098860#9098860
    queues = [deque() for _ in repeat(None, count)]

    def replica(queue: deque) -> Iterable[Domain]:
        while True:
            if not queue:
                try:
                    element = next(iterator)
                except StopIteration:
                    return
                element_copies = copy(element,
                                           count=count)
                for sub_queue, element_copy in zip(queues, element_copies):
                    sub_queue.append(element_copy)
            yield queue.popleft()

    return tuple(replica(queue) for queue in queues)
```

Pros:

- handles nesting on deeper levels or even mixed elements like both iterables and non-iterables on the same level,
- may be extended for user-defined structures (e.g. for making independent deep copies of them).

Cons:

- less readable (but as we know ["practicality beats purity"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python)),
- provides some overhead related to dispatching (but it's ok since it is based on dictionary lookup which has `O(1)` complexity).

---

## Test

### Preparation

Let's define our nested iterable as follows

```
nested_iterable = [range(10 ** index) for index in range(1, 7)]
```

Since iterators creation says nothing about underlying copies performance, let's define function for iterators exhausting (described [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-September/023488.html))

```
exhaust_iterable = deque(maxlen=0).extend
```

### Time

Using `timeit` package

```
import timeit

def naive(): exhaust_iterable(copy_nested_iterable(nested_iterable))

def improved(): exhaust_iterable(copy_iterable(nested_iterable))

print('naive approach:', min(timeit.repeat(naive)))
print('improved approach:', min(timeit.repeat(improved)))
```

I have on my laptop with Windows 10 x64 in Python 3.5.4

```
naive approach: 5.1863865
improved approach: 3.5602296000000013
```

### Memory

Using [`memory_profiler` package](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/)

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    78     17.2 MiB     17.2 MiB   @profile
    79                             def profile_memory(nested_iterable: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> None:
    80     68.6 MiB     51.4 MiB       result = list(flatten(flatten(copy_nested_iterable(nested_iterable))))
```

for "naive" approach and

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    78     17.2 MiB     17.2 MiB   @profile
    79                             def profile_memory(nested_iterable: Iterable[Iterable[Any]]) -> None:
    80     68.7 MiB     51.4 MiB       result = list(flatten(flatten(copy_iterable(nested_iterable))))
```

for "improved" one.

**Note**: I've made different runs of script because making them at once won't be representative since second statement will reuse previously created under-the-hood `int` objects.

---

## Conclusion

As we can see both functions have similar performance, but the last one supports deeper levels of nesting and looks pretty extensible.

### Advertisement

I've added "improved" solution to [`lz` package](https://pypi.org/project/lz) from `0.4.0` version which can be used like

```
>>> from lz.replication import replicate
>>> iterable = iter(range(5))
>>> list(map(list, replicate(iterable,
                             count=3)))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

It is property-based tested using [`hypothesis` framework](https://hypothesis.works/), so we may be sure that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your question: *How to deep copy a nested iterable?*

You can use `deepcopy` from the standard library:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> 
>>> ni = [1, [2,3,4]]
>>> ci = deepcopy(ni)
>>> ci[1][0] = "Modified"
>>> ci
[1, ['Modified', 3, 4]]
>>> ni
[1, [2,3,4]]
```

## Update

@Azat Ibrakov said: *you are working with sequences, try to deepcopy a file object for example (hint: it will fail)*

No, deepcopy on a file object, won't fail, you can deep copy a file object, demonstration:

```
import copy

with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.writelines(["{}\n".format(i) for i in range(100)])

with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = [1, [f]]
    c = copy.deepcopy(l)
    print(isinstance(c[1][0], file))  # Prints  True.
    print("\n".join(dir(c[1][0])))
```

Prints:

```
True
__class__
__delattr__
__doc__
__enter__
__exit__
__format__
__getattribute__
...
write
writelines
xreadlines
```

## The problem is in the concept.

According to Python Iterator protocol, the items contained by some container are obtained executing the `next` function see the [docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

You won't have all items of an object that implements the iterator protocol (as file objects) until you traverse the whole iterator (execute `next()` until StopIteration exception is raised).

That's because there is no way you can tell for sure the result of executing the `next` (`__next__` for Python 2.x) method of an iterator

See the following example:

```
import random

class RandomNumberIterator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.internal_it = range(10)  # For later demostration on deepcopy

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count == 10:
            raise StopIteration
        return random.randint(0, 1000)

ri = RandomNumberIterator()

for i in ri:
    print(i)  # This will print randor numbers each time.
              # Can you come out with some sort of mechanism to be able
              # to copy **THE CONTENT** of the `ri` iterator?
```

Again you could:

```
from copy import deepcopy

cri = deepcopy(ri)

for i in cri.internal_it:
    print(i)   # Will print numbers 0..9
               # Deepcopy on ri successful!
```

> A file object is an especial case here, there are file handlers involved, before, you see you can deepcopy a file object, but it will have `closed` state.

## Alternative.

You could call `list` on your iterables, that will automatically evaluate iterables an then you will be able to test again **THE ITERABLE'S CONTENT**.

Returning to files:

```
with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
         f.writelines(["{}\n".format(i) for i in range(5)])

with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(list(f))  # Prints ['0\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n']
```

## So, resuming

You can deepcopy nested iterables but, you can't evaluate iterables while they are being copied, it just has no sense (remember `RandomNumberIterator`).

If you need to test on the iterables **CONTENT** you need to evaluate them.

Comment: you are working with sequences, try to deepcopy a file object for example (hint: it will fail)

Comment: which Python version are you using? for Python 3 `deepcopy`ing file object will end up with `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object`

Comment: what do you mean by "you can't evaluate iterables while they are being copied", I can succesfully make copies of plain iterables with `itertools.tee` and then evaluate each one of them independently, even potentially infinite ones

Comment: in Python 2.7 if I do `copy.deepcopy(file)` I get
`<closed file '<uninitialized file>', mode '<uninitialized file>' at 0x7f4a99ac3930>` and after trying to iterate over it like `list(file_copy)` it raises `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`, while original one works as expected, so no, you can't make functioning copy of  file object with `copy.deepcopy` function

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov , in your code samples you're using type annotations, so, I assume you're using Python 3.x , so, I've used Python 3x as well for my answer. On the other hand, the file object, Is not the same as the file content.

Comment: I know what file object is and what is file contents, I don't know what Python you are using, but your code doesn't work in Python 3.3+ and Python 2.7 for both Windows and Linux, so I don't know what are you trying to sell me here, also there may be user-defined iterable structures that has no support for `copy.deepcopy`